# Flutter Drawer is not working on pages except home

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, flutter-layout, flutter-drawer

I have a page that contains body and a drawer, which opens after signin in.

The problem is the drawer only works when it is set as a Home page of MaterialApp, but in my case, Home page is my login page where user should login to proceed

Is there any way to make it work without setting as home?
As i am new to flutter i just stuck here, and i need your help! Thank you in advance for any assistance.

the main page

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController _emailContoller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: OurLogin(
        key2: _key,
        emailContoller: _emailContoller,
        passwordController: _passwordController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

part of the home page (that opens after login)

```
class Home extends KFDrawerContent {
  Home({
    Key key,
  });

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
                      child: Material(
                        shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.menu,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          onPressed: widget.onMenuPressed,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```

the drawer

```
    class MainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MainWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MainWidgetState createState() => _MainWidgetState();
}

class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  KFDrawerController _drawerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _drawerController = KFDrawerController(
      initialPage: ClassBuilder.fromString('Home'),
      items: [
        KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text:
              Text('Home', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18)),
          icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white),
          page: Home(),
        ),
        KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text: Text(
            'Profile',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Colors.white),
          page: Profile(),
        ),
        KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text: Text(
            'Notifications',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active, color: Colors.white),
          page: ClassBuilder.fromString('Notifications'),
        ),
        KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text: Text(
            'Stats',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.trending_up, color: Colors.white),
          page: Stats(),
        ),
        KFDrawerItem.initWithPage(
          text: Text(
            'Schedules',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.av_timer, color: Colors.white),
          page: Schedules(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: KFDrawer(
        controller: _drawerController,
        header: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('images/image.jpg'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text('Scarlett Johansson',
                        style:
                            new TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.white)),
                    new SizedBox(height: 2),
                    new Text('Actress',
                        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey)),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        footer: KFDrawerItem(
          text: Text(
            'Logout',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(31, 58, 47, 1.0),
              Color.fromRGBO(31, 58, 47, 1.0)
            ],
            tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: put the drawer on the Scaffold of every page where you want the drawer to appear

Comment: @Jimmy already did it on every page, the drawer itself appears, but it is not opening by clicking, when it is not set as home page of the application as i mentioned, is there anything else i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue has been resolved, sharing the solution as it can be helpful:

the problem was that after logging in, it was pushing to the Home page, but the home page was also containing drawer widget, so i also needed to indicate path to drawer widget for this to work.

i did it like that

```
//login page

     Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Stack(
                children: [
                  Home(),
                  MainWidget(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
```